# Insert an image to a table with insert command

Tags: sql-server

I have a table:

```
create table Country(
name char(30) not null primary key,
regulations varchar(555) not null,
img image not null)
```

How do i insert an image with an insert command?
i understand that for UPDATE i should use:

```
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'image..Path..here', Single_Blob) as img
```

but how can i insert the image with an insert command, without doing update?
What should i write in the third value?

```
insert into Country VALUES('Usa','http://www.diving.org.il', WHAT?)
```

Comment: As a side note, you should use varbinary(max) instead of image. The image datatype has been deprecated since 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Country
SELECT 'USA', 'HTTP...', BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'image..Path..here', Single_Blob) as img
```

Comment: I'm getting:

    Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\sign1" does not exist.

I'm using the same machine as the SQL Server (my own computer).
Why can't sql recognize the image?

Comment: From the error you got it seems like you didn't include the file extension in your path? (.jpg for example)